# EnityManagerFactory Singleton. Please just check out?

Tags: java, jpa, singleton

I am just cruious if this looks solid. It gives no errors but I just want to double check as I am having a pooling issue with c3p0. Just checking to see if anything here is the cause. Thank you in advance!

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;


public class EntityManagerFactorySingleton {
    private static EntityManagerFactorySingleton singleton;
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

public EntityManagerFactorySingleton(){
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(ConfigList.getProperty(Config.PERSISTENCE_UNIT), System.getProperties());
}

public synchronized static EntityManagerFactorySingleton getInstance() {
   if(singleton == null) {
    singleton = new EntityManagerFactorySingleton();
   }
   return singleton;
}

public EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory(){
    return emf;
}
```

}

Comment: You might want to make the constructor private.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not "solid":

- constructor must be private for a singleton
- you shouldn't have the `getInstance()` method synchronised, although you need to perform the initialisation thread-safe. That's because after initialization, all the threads that need the instance will have to wait for each other (and that's a useless bottleneck).
  Only if your instance is null, call a synchronized (private) method that performs the initialisation; inside that method, check *again* if the instance is null. Another approach is to have a private inner class `SingletonHolder` that holds the instance, so you'll rely on the class-loader for performing the thread-safe initialisation.

However, if you can't (don't want to) avoid using a singleton, a very good choice would be an enum with only one constant defined: INSTANCE;

```
public enum EntityManagerFactorySingleton {
    INSTANCE;

    // all your code -- fields, constructor, instance / static methods get in here
    // you can still have the `getInstance()` static method returning INSTANCE, if you want.
}
```

The only drawback is that you cannot perform lazy initialisation for the `INSTANCE`, but you're now thread-safe and ready for serialization or cloning issues without any effort.

Answer (score 0):

1. <s>The code is not thread safe.</s> (Sorry, missed the `synchronized`)
2. [You should not use singletons](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scottdensmore/archive/2004/05/25/140827.aspx).

Instead, use a DI framework like [Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#overview-dependency-injection), [guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) or maybe your deployment envionment already offers one.

This will make your code much more robust and much more simple to test.

Comment: How is it not thread safe (provided the constructor is declared private)?

Comment: I agree with what you're saying about using a DI framework, but how is it not threadsafe (bearing in mind constructor needs to be private).

Comment: Also re: "You should not use singletons" link.  It states "What ends up happening is that the dependencies in your design are hidden inside the code, and not visible by examining the interfaces of your classes and methods. " - does DI solve that?  I think you'll struggle to see all dependencies of a class via interfaces.  no!? Also there's no reason the singleton instance can't be exposed to the outside world as an interface.  In short I agree with the article if its business entities you are making a Singleton, but in the example given here I think it's an ok pattern.

Comment: @*: Sorry, I missed the `synchronized` keyword in the code. If you do it this way, it's thread safe. Updated my answer.

Comment: @planetjones: Most DI systems collect the dependencies in one or a few places. The problem is not with exposing singletons, it's with changing them. Many tests will need different singletons - that doesn't fit into the tiny horizon of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

To **answer your question** - I think you should make the constructor private, to ensure other Classes cannot instantiate another EntityManagerFactorySingleton.  However, if that is not happening, then I can see no reason why this class would be causing a pooling issue.